# How to sum all the numbers of one column in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I need to know how to sum all the numbers of a column in a CSV file.

For example. My data looks like this:

```
column  count   min max sum mean
80  29573061    2   40  855179253   28.92
81  28861459    2   40  802912711   27.82
82  28165830    2   40  778234605   27.63
83  27479902    2   40  754170015   27.44
84  26800815    2   40  729443846   27.22
85  26127825    2   40  701704155   26.86
86  25473985    2   40  641663075   25.19
87  24827383    2   40  621981569   25.05
88  24189811    2   40  602566423   24.91
89  23566656    2   40  579432094   24.59
90  22975910    2   40  553092863   24.07
91  22412345    2   40  492993262   22
92  21864206    2   40  475135290   21.73
93  21377772    2   40  461532152   21.59
94  20968958    2   40  443921856   21.17
95  20593463    2   40  424887468   20.63
96  20329969    2   40  364319592   17.92
97  20157643    2   40  354989240   17.61
98  20104046    2   40  349594631   17.39
99  20103866    2   40  342152213   17.02
100 20103866    2   40  335379448   16.6
#But it's separated by tabs
```

The code I've write so far is:

```
import sys
import csv

def ErrorCalculator(file):
        reader = csv.reader(open(file), dialect='excel-tab' )

        for row in reader:
                PxCount = 10**(-float(row[5])/10)*float(row[1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
        ErrorCalculator(sys.argv[1])
```

For this particular code I need to sum all the numbers in PxCount and divide by the sum of all numbers in row[1]...

I'll be so grateful if tell me how to sum the numbers of a column or if you help me with this code.

Also if you can give me a tip to skip the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call "reader.next()" right after instantiating the reader to discard the first line.

To sum the PxCount, just set `sum = 0` before your loop and `sum += PxCount` after you calculate it for each row.

PS You might find the csv.DictReader helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep a running total using an ["augmented assignment" +=](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements):

```
total=0
for row in reader:
        PxCount = 10**(-float(row[5])/10)*float(row[1])
        total+=PxCount
```

---

To skip the first line (header) in the csv file:

```
with open(file) as f:
    next(f)  # read and throw away first line in f
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel-tab' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `DictReader` will result in far clearer code. `Decimal` will give you better precision. Also try to follow python naming conventions and use lowercase names for functions and variables.

```
import decimal

def calculate(file):
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(file), dialect='excel-tab' )
    total_count = 0
    total_sum = 0
    for row in reader:
        r_count = decimal.Decimal(row['count'])
        r_sum = decimal.Decimal(row['sum'])
        r_mean = decimal.Decimal(row['mean'])
        # not sure if the below formula is actually what you want
        total_count += 10 ** (-r_mean / 10) * r_count
        total_sum += r_sum
    return total_count / total_sum
```